# Is it correct to say "I am blowing my hair dry"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

There is a phrase

> [**blow-dry** verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow-dry)
>
> Definition of blow-dry transitive verb
>
> : to dry and usually style (hair) with a blow-dryer intransitive verb
>
> : to dry hair with a blow-dryer

So, we can say "**I blow-dried my hair**"

However, sometimes, I don't have a hair-drier and I want to dry my wet hair by turning my hair to a fan and let it blow my hair until it dries out.

Is it correct to say "**I am blowing my hair dry**" the same way we say "**the wind blew the door shut**" (**blow + Noun + adj**)?

Comment: I would think that you can be said to blow-dry your hair in any artificial current of air, not just that from a hair-drier.

Comment: The only possible problem with "I am blowing my hair dry" isn't anything grammatical, but rather that no one will hear you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Blow-drying** requires a rather sophisticated *[hair dryer](https://www.vega.co.in/blog/post/5-hair-dryer-uses-and-tips-to-get-rid-of-that-frizz.html)* and skill. It's often used by hairdressers to add volume and body to hair. The skill lies in making hair look smooth, shiny and soft to the touch. It needs practice, time, and a certain hand-dexterity to achieve the same results at home but it can be done.

- She blow-dried her hair until it looked as though she'd stepped out of a hair salon.
- He spent hours blow-drying his hair.

For mortals who lack the necessary tools, skill, and patience, it's just "dry".

- I spend about five minutes drying my hair (either with a towel or hair dryer).
- How long have you been using that hair dryer? I need to get into the bathroom.

If someone told me they were *blowing their hair dry*, I might think they were blowing with their mouth to dry their own hair, an impossible feat.

Answer (score 1):

If I heard somebody say, "I am blowing my hair dry," my reaction would be to ask them, "You mean you're blow drying your hair?" because I thought they misspoke.

Whether you are using a blow dryer or a fan is irrelevant, except that the fan won't do a very good job.